# Configure Spring Bean using XML through Property other than String (using Properties File)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-properties

I have a Spring Bean defined as:

```
<bean id="loyaltyPointsExpiringJobTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="name" value="Loyalty Points Expiring Job Trigger" />
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="loyaltyPointsExpiringJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="${prop.loyalty.expiring.points.job.cron}"/>
        <property name="timeZone" value="${prop.loyalty.expiring.points.timezone}"/>
    </bean>
```

However, the property `prop.loyalty.expiring.points.timezone` is causing `TypeMismatchException` with the message:

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.TimeZone' for property 'timeZone'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid time zone specification '${prop.loyalty.expiring.points.timezone}'

Please guide.

Comment: What is value `prop.loyalty.expiring.points.timezone` ?

Comment: Its value is currently set to UTC in one of the properties file.

Comment: I think you need to write a custom Converter, to tell Spring how to convert Strings into Timezones - the error indicates it wants to do it, but doesn't know how...

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward, you may need to define a bean for your `timeZone` object, and find out a constructor that uses string, pass the required values.

Comment: timeZone does not have any constructor that takes the String parameter.

Comment: Can you let me know the package that it belongs to? Please share the constructor of `timeZone` class

Comment: It's java.util.TimeZone

Comment: Can you try this ?
 
`<bean id="time" class="java.util.TimeZone" factory-method="getTimeZone">
      <constructor-arg value="${prop.loyalty.expiring.points.timezone}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>`